# While printing out words that start with 's',my jupyter notebook is not responding is that the code error or notebook problem?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

While running the code to print the words starting with 's', jupyter note book is not responding

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this s'
lis=st.split()
i=0
res=[]
while i<len(lis):
    if lis[i][0]=='s':
        res.append(list[i])
        i+=1
print(res)
```

Comment: Your code is boken.   You only update i if you find and s.  You are in an infinite loop.  Reduce indentation of i+=1

Answer (score 3):

Your code gets stuck if the first word in the list does not start with an s change the i increment to be outisde the if as follows:

```py
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this s'
lis=st.split()
i=0
res=[]
while i<len(lis):
    if lis[i][0]=='s':
        res.append(list[i])
    i+=1
print(res)
```

EDIT: An improved version of this code

```py
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this s'
res=[]
for s in st.split():
    if s[0] == 's':
        res.append(s)

print(res)
```

You can also use list comprehension

```py
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this s'
res = [s for s in st.split() if s[0] == 's']
print(res)
# prints ['start', 's', 's']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it in a more pythonic way like this:

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this s' 
lis=st.split()
results = []
for word in lis:
    if word.startswith("s"):
        results.append(word)
print(results)
```

O/P:

```
['start', 's', 's']
```

Answer (score 1):

A for loop is better in this case. When you split your string, you will get a list of words. Use for instead of while.

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this s'
lis=st.split()
res=[]
for word in lis:
    if(word.startswith("s")):
        res.append(word)
```

Comment: Yes split works. But if your string contains punctuation such as ,!@ then split won't split the punctuation.     Eg-> st = "Print only apples ,strawberry". If you give st.split(' '), you will get ['apples',',strawberry']. Here even though strawberry starts with 's', because of the punctuation we will miss it. word_tokenize however splits everything into tokens, even the punctuations. same set will give ['apples',',','strawberry'] with word_tokenize.

Comment: Okay, but i need to say to use regex, instead of a whole big difficult `nltk` to use just this

Comment: It's a little strange to use `nltk` here

Answer (score 0):

You're using `i` to keep track of the count (`i=0`) and the iterables (`if lis[i][0]=='s'`)

I'd suggest using [enumerate](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate) to keep track of the count

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this s'
lis=st.split()
res=[]

for c, i in enumerate(lis):
    if i[0] == 's': # here, you can also use i[0].lower() if you want to count words that might start with a capital 's'
        res.append(i)

print(c) # keep track of the number of things being iterated over
print(res) # the list of items starting with s
print(len(res)) # how many items starting with s
```

EDIT: answered before the question was edited.

Comment: No no no that `enumerate` doesn't do all

Comment: Sorry @U9-Forward, what do you mean? I wasn't sure if they want to track the iterable count or whether they're tracking it simply to exit the `while` loop, or (because of the indentation of `i+=1`) want to count the number of matching iterables. So I showed how to do all 3. `enumerate` tends to make code cleaner too

Comment: `c` will be number of words in `st`

Comment: Then that means you don't know what the question is about.

Comment: Or perhaps that your level of literacy is too low to realise "c will be number of words in st" and "print(c) # keep track of the number of things being iterated over" means the same thing/too low to comprehend my first comment? In remedial English: **it wasn't clear what OP was trying to do**